# Angular Form Validations Required field + optional field

Tags: angular, forms, validation

So my question is. I have a very huge form to fill in 200 input fields+ and I have one field required (the title) but I also wanna check that they fill in at least one other field. doesn't matter which one. but once that requirement is met they can submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-y1ykx8?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example. You only need to set a Validator to one field and then check onSubmit all other fields values:

```
  onSubmit(): void {
    let anyOtherControlIsFilled = false;

    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((key) => {
      if (!this.form.controls[key].validator) {
        if (
          this.form.controls[key].value !== null &&
          this.form.controls[key].value !== ''
        ) {
          console.log('Passt');
          anyOtherControlIsFilled = true;
        }
      }
    });

    if (this.form.valid && anyOtherControlIsFilled) {
      this.submitted = true;
      alert('All ok');
    } else {
      this.submitted = true;
      alert('Error');
      return;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value, null, 2));
  }
```

Greetings, Flo

Comment: I have changed the example. You can simple use `this.form.controls[key].touched`. Touched means if the input field was focused. So if it touched you can check if the current value !== the start value.

Answer (score 0):

Add validator to FormGroup to check all inputs.

```
new FormGroup(
  {
    requiredControl: new FormControl(initialValue, [Validators.required]),
    control1: new FormControl(...),
    ...
    control200: new FormControl(...)
  },
  [someValueValidator()]
)

private someValueValidator() {
  return (controls: AbstractControl) => {
   // check if any non-required control is set then return null, 
   // otherwise return ValidationError
  }
}
```